# How to generate all configurations of a given length in Python

Tags: python, recursion

I am trying to generate a list of all configurations where in each configuration is as follows. Each configuration is a list of length `n` whose entry can take on values `0-q` where `q` is a positive integer. For example if `q=1` then I am trying to generate a list of all possible binary lists of length `n`. So if `n=2,q=1` then the desired output is `[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]`. For an arbitrary `q`, the desired output list is of size `(q+1)^n` because there `q+1` choices for each element of the list of length `n`. For example, for `n=3,q=2`, the desired output is `[[0,0,0],[0,0,1],[0,0,2],[0,1,0],..]` and the output list is of size `3^3=27`.

I have tried to do this using recursion for `q=1` but am not sure how to write efficient code for arbitrary `q`? Here is the code and output for `q=1`.

```
def generateAllSpinConfigs(n,arr,l,i):
    if i == n: 
        l.append(arr[:]) 
        return

    arr[i] = 0
    generateAllSpinConfigs(n,arr,l,i+1)  
    arr[i] = 1
    generateAllSpinConfigs(n,arr,l,i+1)

    return l

n=2
l=[]  
arr=[None]*n
print(generateAllSpinConfigs(n,arr,l,0))

>>[[0,0],[0,1],[1,0],[1,1]]
```

Comment: Why not just `itertools.product()`?

Comment: @JohnColeman I see, thanks. The documentation says ```product(A, B)``` returns the same as ```((x,y) for x in A for y in B)```. So if ```n=3,q=2``` then how can I use ```itertools.product()```? Because if I do ```itertools.product([0,1,2],[0,1,2])``` then It would only create a list of tuples where as I'm looking for a list of lists where each inner list is of size ```n=3```.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`itertools.product` does what you want:

```
def generate_configurations(n,q):
    return [list(p) for p in itertools.product(range(q+1),repeat = n)]

print(generate_configurations(2,1))

#[[0, 0], [0, 1], [1, 0], [1, 1]]
```